# How to optimize the below VB Code? It is taking lot of time to run and Excel is hanging every time

Tags: vba, excel, rtm

### I am creating a Requirement Traceablity M matrix in the Excel sheet and below VB code is taking more time to execute and excel sheet is hanging for 5 minutes every time I enter something in a cell.

---

### VBA code:

```
Function MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)

    Dim xDic As New Dictionary
    Dim xRows As Long
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    xRows = LookupRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To xRows
        If LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells(i).Value = Lookupvalue Then
            xDic.Add LookupRange.Columns(ColumnNumber).Cells(i).Value, ""
        End If
    Next
    xStr = ""
    MultipleLookupNoRept = xStr
    If xDic.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To xDic.Count - 1
            xStr = xStr & xDic.Keys(i) & ","
        Next
        MultipleLookupNoRept = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    End If 

End Function
```

Comment: There is no need to check if the value already exists in the dictionary, just do `xDic(LookupValue) = ""`. Also convert `LookupRange` to 2d array before loop `aRows = LookupRange.Value`, and process the array within loop instead of the range.

Comment: RTM is requirement traceability Matrix

Comment: If no-one manages to work the word REDEMPTION into their answer I will be sorely disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

↓Concatenate all the keys in a Dictionary ↓

> ```
> Join(Dictionary.Key(), ",")
> ```

```
Function MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer) As String

    Dim xDic As New Dictionary
    Dim xRows As Long
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    xRows = LookupRange.Rows.count
    For i = 1 To xRows
        If LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells(i).Value = Lookupvalue Then
            xDic.Add LookupRange.Columns(ColumnNumber).Cells(i).Value, ""
        End If
    Next

    If xDic.count > 0 Then
        MultipleLookupNoRept = Join(xDic.Keys(), ",")
    End If

End Function
```

---

Here is the ultra modified version of the code.  The previous code should process 10K rows in 2-5 seconds.

```
Function MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer) As String

    Dim addresses As Variant, values As Variant
    Dim r As Long

    With LookupRange.Parent
        With Intersect(LookupRange.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
            values = .Value
            addresses = .Columns(ColumnNumber).Value
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For r = 1 To UBound(values)
            If values(r, 1) = Lookupvalue And r <= UBound(addresses) And addresses(r, 1) <> "" Then
                .Add addresses(r, 1)
            End If
        Next

        MultipleLookupNoRept = Join(.ToArray(), ",")
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Now it is getting hanged more than 5 mins.. It is not optimized. Still not working

Comment: @SHASHANKBalaganchi I appended another version of the function that trims the range to fit the data.  The only way that it would take the previous answer that long to process is if `LookupRange` had +500K cells.

Comment: Superb Code @TinMan. Very happy . The Ultra version is awesome and working perfectly. did not expect so fast

Comment: At your service!!  Happy Coding :)

Comment: Wondering if [FIND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) would speed it up a bit more.

Comment: Now it is working as soon as i tab out from the cell.. Not sure if more speed up is required.

Comment: Lol..I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  There is no need to further optimise this code, arrays are super fast.  You might like this articel:  [EXCEL VLOOKUP VS INDEX MATCH VS SQL VS VBA](https://analystcave.com/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-vs-sql-performance/).

Comment: @TinMan  Yep, you're right.  I wasn't thinking about the array side of it - just finding it on the sheet which will always be slower than an array.